# Error al desinstalar mysql-server-5.5

Tags: mysql

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de poder usar workbench, y estoy intentando desinstalar y volver a instalar mysql-server-5.5, pero no me deja.
Este es el mensaje de error, ¿Alguien me podria ayudar?

> debconf: DbDriver "passwords" 
>   warning: /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat is locked by another process: Recurso no disponible temporalmente
>
> debconf: DbDriver "templatedb": 
>   /var/cache/debconf/templates.dat is locked by another process: Recurso
>   no disponible temporalmente
>
> (Leyendo la base de datos ... 191372
>   ficheros o directorios instalados actualmente.) Desinstalando
>   mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.58-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
>
> debconf: DbDriver
>   "passwords" warning: /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat is locked by
>   another process: Recurso no disponible temporalmente
>
> debconf: DbDriver
>   "templatedb": /var/cache/debconf/templates.dat is locked by another
>   process: Recurso no disponible temporalmente
>
> dpkg: error al procesar
>   el paquete mysql-server-5.5 (--remove):  el subproceso instalado el
>   script pre-removal devolvió el código de salida de error 1
>
> debconf:
>   DbDriver "passwords" warning: /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat is
>   locked by another process: Recurso no disponible temporalmente
>
> debconf: DbDriver "templatedb": /var/cache/debconf/templates.dat is
>   locked by another process: Recurso no disponible temporalmente
>
> dpkg:
>   error al reorganizar:  el subproceso instalado el script
>   post-installation devolvió el código de salida de error 1 Se
>   encontraron errores al procesar:  mysql-server-5.5

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba si no tienes abierto otro manejador de paquetes (synaptic, aptitude).

Verifica cuál es el proceso que está usando esos archivo en uso:

```
sudo lsof | grep /var/cache/debconf
```

Y si no encuentras ese proceso, o no logras detenerlo, o no encuentras esos archivos, o simplemente no logras que el respectivo proceso los libere, aplica

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/debconf/*.dat
```

Al reinstalar `mysql-server` eventualmente esos archivos de caché serán recreados cuando se necesiten. Esa es la idea de los cachés.

Comment: Lo hice, me soluciono lo del apt-get, pero ahora al hacer apt-get install mysql-server, cuando empieza a configurar mysql-server-5.5, me pone "mysql stop/waiting" y se queda ahi indefinidamente

Comment: Revisa el log de errores de mysql (puede estar en `/var/log/mysql` ). Eso que te pasa pareciera ocurrir porque el servicio no logra iniciar, y eso a su vez puede ser porque le falten permisos en alguna carpeta

Answer (score 0):

Necesitamos algo más de información....
* Se supone que lo estas usando en un servidor Linux .. ¿Que distribución?
* ¿Que comando has usado para desinstalarlo?
* Si el error es del programa "workbench" ¿Porqué desinstalar el servidor? ¿No es mejor corregir el fallo del Wokbench, hay veces que solo es un fallo de la inicialización del "keyring" al iniciarse el Workbench?

De todas formas:

1) Desinstalación de mysql-server

- Lo estas desinstalando como root (supongo)
- Si da errores como root simplemente para el servicio de mysql y realiza de nuevo la desinstalación...

2) Porque desinstalar y volver a instalar ¿?
 - No es mejor un "reinstall", por ejemplo si usas Debian o Ubuntu (apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server-5.5)

3) Que error te daba WorkBench ... a lo mejor era más fácil solucionar esto que desinstalar y volver a instalar ...

Comment: En el workbench simplemente me ponia que no podia conectar. Si intentaba entrar desde terminal, me daba un error en mysqld.sock... si no recuerdo mal